# Is log locally strongly concave?

Tags: convex-analysis

Is $g(x) = \log f(x)$ locally strongly concave if $f$ is a linear function? What if $f$ is a homogeneous function of degree 1?

Comment: Let $f(x)=x$ which is linear. Then $g(x)$ is concave. Are you sure this is what you wanted to ask?

Comment: $\log(x)$ is concave, but it's not strongly concave. The question is: "is it locally strongly concave?"

Comment: Look at the Hessian.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that $f$ is differentiable and maps to the positives ($f:\mathbb{R}\to ]0,\infty[$), we can study its derivatives. Notice that:

$$g''(x)=\frac{f''(x)}{f(x)}+\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)^2.$$

Concavity is then met whenever $g''(x)<0$, equivalently:

$$f''(x)f(x)<\left(f'(x)\right)^2.$$